# Android draw certain pixels of a bitmap

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

Ok so I want to have a bitmap where it is invisible but if you touch it, then the area that is touched will show. This might not seem useful by itself, but I just want to know how to do it so I can apply it to what I really want to do. So how would you do this in android where you only draw certain pixels of a bitmap?

Comment: use a BitmapShader in a custom View

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point would be Roman Guy's ["Fun with shaders"](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/) recipe, which should get you pretty close:

> Thus by moving a shape over the canvas you can reveal different parts of the bitmap.

The basic steps include:

Create an **alpha mask** (the linked example uses another bitmap for this):

```
private static Bitmap convertToAlphaMask(Bitmap b) {
    Bitmap a = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(a);
    c.drawBitmap(b, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
    return a;
}

Bitmap mask;
mask = convertToAlphaMask(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spot_mask));
```

Create a `Paint` instance with a **shader** to draw the mask with:

```
private static Shader createShader(Bitmap b) {
    return new BitmapShader(b, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
}

Shader targetShader = createShader(mTargetBitmap);
paint.setShader(targetShader);
```

Finally, **draw** the mask with the shader:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, 0.0f, 0.0f, mPaint);
}
```

Now, in stead of animating the 'light beam' over a predefined path (as in the example code), hook it up to touch events and go from there. I.e. you may have to keep track of the touched areas and/or paths to get the desired effect.

Comment: I don't really know how shaders work at all though.. Is there any way to do it without using shaders?

Comment: And also when you instantiated the canvas you put in a bitmap parameter, what does that mean? When you called c.drawBitmap where is the drawing being done?

Comment: Have you already read through the linked article, as well as the preceding recipe? I think that should answer most of your questions. There's also a full example project that you can play around with. It's certainly possible to do it without a shader (probably less efficient too), but the idea will be the same: to 'reveal' parts of the bitmap by 'erasing' a layer on top of that. Think of it as cleaning a window full of dust. :)

Comment: Thanks and I did read the articles, but like I said I don`t understand what drawing to a bitmap means.. drawing to the screen is easy to understand but how do you draw to something that`s already, like, a bitmap? Seems kind of confusing..

Comment: Drawing to a bitmap and drawing to the screen are two very similar things: In both cases you have a rectangular area that makes up a grid of pixels. Drawing to a bitmap is basically just changing the colour of those pixels, regardless of whether they're being displayed (drawn) on screen or not. I.e. consider a command line program that adds a watermark to a photo. You execute it, it takes each photo, adds the watermark and saves the result into a file. You won't see the visual result until you open the file, but the pixels in the watermark area will have changed regardless.

Comment: Do I have to draw a bitmap with the main canvas(the one you get with the call to surface holder.lockcanvas()) before I see any changes that I made with a second canvas that was drawing to that particular bitmap?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. A `Canvas` is the tool you use to draw onto a bitmap's pixels. If you've been drawing to an off-screen bitmap, then in order to visualize that bitmap, you'll have to draw it using the canvas that renders to the screen. I.e. for a plain `View` that would be the `Canvas` that is supplied in the overridable `onDraw()` method.

Comment: Wow. It was such an easy approach. Thanks.